# listview center not working

Tags: android, listview, center

I have a problem with a ListView that won't be CENTRALIZED !!!

here is my MainActivity :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView storiesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String[] strories =     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.storiesTitles);

        ArrayAdapter storiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewlayout, R.id.textViewList, strories);

        storiesList.setAdapter(storiesAdapter);
    }
}
```

My Main layout XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="habworks.com.gibranstories.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="قصص جبران"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/share"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/appsBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/apps"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/emailBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/mail"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/exitBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/exit"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and finally my custom XML for the ListView called : 
listviewlayout.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewList"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:background="#FF5566" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and the result is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8qQ5.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
android:gravity="center"
```

targets the content of the view.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

on the other hand, sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

Answer (score 0):

try it listviewlayout.xml :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    **android:gravity="center"**
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewList"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:background="#FF5

566" />
```